# Variable initialization in genetic algorith coding in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, initialization, genetic-algorithm

I am writing a genetic algorithm code in matlab and I want to initialize a variable called `b`, while it is a continuous variable between 0 and 40, I want matlab start it with 40 and continue calculating it during the ga process. I defined `b=0+40.*rand(25,12);` so it gives a random marix of 25 & 12 between 0 & 40. But I want the matlab to start with `b=40` and then continue the calculation. Could you please help me to solve this issue? Thanks for any help 
regards 
Elnaz

Comment: `But I want the matlab to start with b=40`, then what is wrong with writing `b=40;` on the first line ?

Comment: . .. or possibly `b = ones(25,12) * 40;` - perhaps b is supposed to be a matrix of 40s.